# Cakephp how can I created a route for accept both id and cat id with maintain path?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have an API prefix route, I have a controller where I'm trying to fetch product, then products by id , then products by category id.

So, I have created a prefix route

```
$routes->scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
        $routes->resources('Shops',[
            'prefix' => 'Api',
            'path' => 'shops',
            'map' => [
                'getProducts' => [
                    'action' => 'getProducts',
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'path' => '/products'
                ],
                'getProductById' => [
                    'action' => 'getProducts',
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'path' => '/products/{id}',
                ],
                'getProductBySubcatId' => [
                    'action' => 'getProducts',
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'path' => '/products/cat/{cat_id}',
                    'subcat_id' => [0-10]
                ],
            ]
        ]);
 });
```

In action actually I'm trying to do

```
public function getProducts($id = null, $cat_id = null)
{   
        if($id)
          -----
        else if($cat_id)
          ----
}
```

I need to fetch the data like

http://localhost:8000/api/shops/products/cat/1.json

Present
For below URL

http://localhost:8000/api/shops/products/1.json

I'm getting params pass

```
protected params => [
'id' => '1',
'pass' => [
   (int) 0 => '1',
],
```

But for catId I'm not getting pass
http://localhost:8000/api/shops/products/cat/1.json

```
protected params => [
'catId' => '1',
'pass' => [ ],
```

Also I'm able to send string as a params for cat id

```
protected params => [
'catId' => 'A',
'pass' => [ ],
```

How can I add catId in pass ? also how can I add a validation that catId always int ?

Comment: You can define custom `pass` configuration in [the `connectOptions` option](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes-for-resource-routes). But don't make your life overly complicated, use separate controller methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using `connectOptions`

```
map [
  // your map 
],
'connectOptions' => [
    'catId' => '[0-9]+',
    'pass' => ['id','catId'],
],
```

For details check [RouteBuilder.php class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/Routing/RouteBuilder.php)

Answer (score 0):

Would try to use the spread operator in you method:

```
public function getProducts(...$params)
{   
   //try to understand spread operator
   debug($params);

   if (count($params) == 2 && !is_number($params[0]) && is_number($params[1]) {
     $id = strval($params[0]);
     $cat_id = intval($params[1]);
   }

  if (count($params) == 1 && is_number($params[0]) {
     $id = null;
     $cat_id = intval($params[0]);
   }
   // ... implement your code     
}
```

Comment: What will be request then ? is it ?
http://localhost:8000/api/miles/products/1/1.json

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/shops/products/cat/1.json